# Replace NA values by an incremental key with label

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

How replace NA values by an incremental key with label?

A toy data.frame:

```
data1 <- c(22,40,72,41,66,66,66)
key <- c(NA,"other",0,0,"other",0,"other")

df<- data.frame(data1,key)
df[df == 0] <- NA
```

my d.f:

```
 data1   key
1    22  <NA>
2    40 other
3    72  <NA>
4    41  <NA>
5    66 other
6    66  <NA>
7    66 other
```

What I did using dplyr package for making a key

```
library (dplyr)
df %>% mutate(key = paste0('id-', 1:n()))
```

My results:

```
  data1  key
1    22 id-1
2    40 id-2
3    72 id-3
4    41 id-4
5    66 id-5
6    66 id-6
7    66 id-7
```

What I want: keeping "others" values

```
 data1   key
1    22  id-1
2    40 other
3    72  id-2
4    41  id-3
5    66 other
6    66  id-4
7    66 other
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First convert df$key to character:

```
df$key <- as.character(df$key)
```

Then

```
df$key[is.na(df$key)] <- paste0('id-', 1:length(df$key[is.na(df$key)]))



> df$key
[1] "id-1"   "other" "id-2"   "id-3"   "other" "id-4"   "other"
```

Or, with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(key = as.character(key),
         key = ifelse(is.na(key), paste0('id-', 1:length(key[is.na(key)])),
                      key))
```

Comment: Great! Can I use dplyr with mutate?

Comment: You can also generate the sequence with `1:sum(is.na(df$key))` which is a little simpler.

Comment: @ Andrew Taylor Great but not keeping my "other" values (converting "other" values to 1 values)

Comment: Are you converting the key factor to character. When I include the `as.character()`, as I do above, I'm not getting that issue

Comment: Sorry, It works , I was testing with my real data (with a mistake...)

Answer (score 4):

Using cumsum and mutate:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(key = ifelse(is.na(key), paste("id", sep = "-", cumsum(is.na(key))),
                      as.character(key)))
```